# HTML Form, getElementById not working inside javascript function. Login Page

Tags: javascript, html

I am confused here, I have html form from which I want to send information to javascript. (which will call offisde for login). Everytime I enter    `var username = document.getElementById("user").value;` inside the function, nothing appears on my console log. But if I take that out, it behaves as normal.

Here my html

```
<form class="form-login">
            <h2 class="form-login-heading">sign in now</h2>
            <div class="login-wrap">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="User ID" name="user" autofocus>
                <br>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="passwd" >
                <button class="btn btn-theme btn-block" Value="Submit" type="submit" onclick="Calculate()"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> SIGN IN</button>
```

Here my javascript

```
<Script>
function Calculate(){

        console.log("In function, test 1");


        var username = document.getElementById("user").value; <-- if remove this, console/alert apper, but add this and no consoles.log appear. Not even the one above



        alert ("Login successfully");
            window.location.replace("index.html");
            //window.location = "index.html"; // Redirecting to other page.
            return false; 
</script>
```

So I am confused on why I cannot used `getElementById` inside my javascript function.

`

Comment: You never set an ID on any element. Do id="user" on the element you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no element with id `user`, you have an input with name `user`, add attribute `id="name"` to it and tthen you should be fine.